# Formula for the length of a vector, given another basis and coordinates.

Tags: geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

Let $\mathbf{u,v,w}$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose a vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ has coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in the basis {$\mathbf{u,v,w}$}. What is the formula for the length of $\mathbf{x}$ in terms of its coordinates and properties of $\mathbf{u,v,w}$?

For context, I'm a first year uni student.

Any hints/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, it's $\lVert x_1\mathbf u+x_2\mathbf v+x_3\mathbf w\rVert$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited it to make it $x$ for the vector instead of $v$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio is that really it? Nothing more, nothing less?

Comment: If you multiply each x-coordinate with its corresponding basis vector and add them up, you'll get the "xyz"-coordinates ( = basis {$(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(0, 0, 1)$}) of x.
Then you can use the Pythagorean formula to calculate the length of x. So to summarize: length(x) = $sqrt((x_1*u)^2 + (x_2*v)^2 + (x_3*w)^2)$.